# How can I create a log that is usable for output, but still allow for output and input in the console

Tags: powershell

```psh
Function LogWrite
{
   Out-file -Append "scan.log"
}

function Test-IsAdmin 
{
    If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(
    [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
    Write-Warning "You do not have Administrator rights to run this script!`nPlease re-run this script as an Administrator!"
        Break
    }
}

function Restart-saned
{
    Get-Service -name TBS | LogWrite
    Stop-Service -name TBS
    Start-Service -name TBS
}
```

Above is a snippet of the code i am trying to use. but i cannot get the "get-service" line to output into the log file. when i do not create a function and instead use:

```psh
Get-Service -name TBS | out-file -append "scan.log"
```

logging works correctly and i get output. is there a way to create a function to simplify the logging in powershell?

Comment: Have you tried using `start-transcript`?

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of a command you would see in batch :

    command >> logname.log

It would create a simple logging process for write commands. I want the log to have certain information placed into it while the script runs (Version numbers, if commands fail, and service restarts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-pipe the special `$input` variable,

```
Function LogWrite
{
   $input | Out-file -Append "scan.log"
}
```

Comment: That works! thank you. Now, question. why does that work, but doesn't work without the $input pipe?  as you may be able to tell, im quite new to writing in powershell.

Comment: `$input` will contain anything you piped into the function.